# Online HDD to save and share documents with my team

Tags: file-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Online file storage services](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/638/online-file-storage-services)

because I have many documents, that I want to share with my team I want to use some online HDD (Cloud) service, where I can save documents, create folders, create pass protected folders etc. and access them from everywhere in the world. Does anyone use such service?

Comment: What type of documents do you require be shared?

Answer (score 1):

You can use services for it:

- http://docs.google.com from Google
- http://docs.com from Microsoft

Or you can just use online storage services like Dropbox. Here is review of most popular storages for it: http://onlinefilestoragereview.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of options for this. Here are 2 that i use that i can recommend.

[DropBox](http://dropbox.com) is the simplest, after installing an agent on your Mac/PC/iPhone etc, it allows you to share a folder on your hard drive with other people, and updates automatically in the background. Sub-folders can be created. It's free to get started, with more space available at a cost.

[Sharefile](http://sharefile.com) is more manual, requiring you to upload files, and set permissions for different users. It's very good for creating time-sensitive shares with co-workers or 3rd parties such as suppliers or other partners. It's a paid service with a free trial.

Answer (score 0):

Am sure there is such a service (Google Docs perhaps). However, another option you may not have thought of is a Network Storage solution. I have a WD Book at home, safely behind my router. It uses MioNet to access the data on it. I can choose to invite users and limit access to the folders. Of course, there are also solutions better tailored to a company.